# Verification on the following statement on number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $a\equiv0\pmod{b}$ and $c\equiv0\pmod{xb}$ then is it true that $(a+c)\equiv0\pmod{(b+xb)}$, where $x$ is an integer?

I have noticed it to be true in many cases, so can anyone verify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $a=9,\  c=24,\  b=3,\ x=4$. Then $a\equiv 0(mod\ b)$ and $c\equiv 0(mod\ xb)$. But it is not the case that $a+c\equiv (mod\ (b+xb))$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $x=1$ and $(a,b,c)=(6,3,9)$. We have $b+xb=2b$. Then certainly $a\equiv 0 \bmod b$ and $c\equiv 0 \bmod xb$, but $a+c=15\not\equiv 0\bmod 2b$.